# How do I remove items from my Windows 8 context menu?

Tags: windows, windows-8, right-click, context-menu

So first, here's what my actual context menu looks like:

[image: context menu items]

These useless options were added by third-party programs, and apparently I can't delete them using the "traditional" programs recommended on the internet (like **ShellExView** or **ShellMenuView** or **CCleaner**, etc), because these menu items just don't appear to be found by them (exception for Kaspersky's and Winrar's menu items, but those I want to keep there).

The menu items that I want to delete are the ones between "*Abrir local do arquivo*" and "*Executar como administrador*".

Any solutions?

Comment: which third parties added those items like "Run with Japanese locale as administrator" ?

Comment: The program is called "AppLocale". I had to install it to play a terror game called White Day.

Comment: It is. I didn't pay attention to all the given responses, apparently Glary Utilities was quoted there too. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Glary Utilities](http://www.glarysoft.com/) has a built-in context menu editor. I've tested it and it works great!

Comment: Well, that solved the problem. I wonder why the other programs didn't list all of the context menu items.